# How to enable mod_rewrite in LAMP on ubuntu?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS linux on my machine. I've already installed LAMP on it. Now I want to enable the mod_rewrite module. I did google a lot and tried lots of tricks but couldn't be able to enable mod_rewrite. Can anyone help me to enable the mod_rewrite? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

TL;DR version -- do the following in your terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```

With explanations -- do the following in your terminal:

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load    ///if it prints out rewrite.load, it's there and ready to go

sudo a2enmod rewrite   //enables the mod

ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load // shows created symlink

sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default   //opens the file in vi (you can also use vim or nano)
```

Replace occurrences of "AllowOverride None" with "AllowOverride all" as necessary

```
sudo service apache2 restart    ///restarts apache
```

Edit your virtual host entry in /etc/apache2/sites-available and add `AllowOverride All` to the DocumentRoot. Your virtual host should ultimately look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com
  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Although this isn't suitable for production environments, it works just fine for local development.

Comment: :Thank you so much, you sid in so easy languge withe description of each step. I've accepted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: @mike - ya great answer, but cud you also mention what to do in production environment or give some links to look up for such cases

Comment: @StacyJ that would be a bit off topic for this question. Thoroughly read the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or httpd.conf comments. Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html for more info

Comment: What does "TL;DR version", mean?

Answer (score 6):

You didn't mention what commands did you try, so I will start with the basic one:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You can also check if mod rewrite is already enable using:

```
apache2ctl -M
```