# I can't remove the index.php from the CodeIgniter URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, indexing

I want to remove index.php from the path in CodeIgniter.

I tried to change the value of index_page in the config file as the following:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

then I tried all these .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

But none of them has worked.

I also tried to to change the uri_protocol to this :

```
   $config['uri_protocol']  = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

But it's still doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem ?

## Edit :

I tried this code to check if the mod_rewrite is enabled :

```
<?php
 if( ! function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); die; }
 $result = ' not available';
 if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules())) $result = 'available';

?>
<p><?php echo apache_get_version(),"</p><p>mod_rewrite $result"; ?></p>
```

And I get this result :

> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>
> mod_rewrite not available

Comment: Try to set url protocol to auto ``$config['uri_protocol']  = 'AUTO';``

Comment: Your htaccess looks fine. Are you sure your web server supports htaccess and has mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: @jonijones I already did this, but the same problem :/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté please check the modification I've made to my post

Comment: See if it helps http://askubuntu.com/q/48362/107606

Comment: httaccess:

`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L] 
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
`

and in application>config>config file 
`
$config['index_page'] = '';
`

Comment: Here is your [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/48363).

Comment: first thing that you should do is how to enable mod_rewrite in ubuntu. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745310/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-lamp-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.. then finally it worked with the following code

just follow these simple steps : 
 1. save the following code into .htaccss file.. 
 2. put it in the main project folder (not the application folder)
 3. rename the "/projectFolderName/" part on 3rd line of the code as
    your project folder name.

## Then you are done. Refresh and see.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /projectFolderName/ 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Inyour .htaccess file write:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

and in your config.php file :

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Make sure yout htaccess is in your root folder not in applications folder.